# Show that the function $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

How to show that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$? I had a hard time understanding this one. Can someone help me with this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the equivalence of Riemann and Darboux integration already? This generally helps a lot with these kinds of problems, because it lets you define your own family of partitions.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @Ian I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: You may be familiar but didn't use the same terminology. Did you use terminology like upper and lower sums? If not, what is your definition of integrability?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the upper and lower sums

Comment: If we consider the integral as the limit of sums of areas notice this function only non-zero and coutably many spots and at those points the function is $1$.  If we can take the base of rectangles at those  points to be arbitrarily small......

Comment: The basic idea is to take small intervals around each of the points $1/n$ and then estimate the upper sum. There is a minor technical obstacle with there being infinitely many of them, but the fix for that is to just jam all but finitely many of those points into one subinterval.

Comment: This sounds to me like a problem of measure theory. You define a measure over your set and then an integral over your measure.